# pgmpy returning incorrect conditional probabilities

Tags: python, probability, bayesian-networks, pgmpy

I'm trying to use the [pgmpy Python package](http://pgmpy.org/) to learn the transition probabilities between a certain set of states, however when I fit the model, I find that the conditional probabilities are incorrect.

As a very simplified example of the sort of issue I'm talking about, consider the Bayesian network consisting of two states, A and B, with a single directed edge running from A to B. And suppose that we have observed that whenever A is zero, B is one, and whenever A is one, B is zero. The code describing this situation is given by:

```
import pandas as pd
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'B': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
model = BayesianModel([('A', 'B')])
model.fit(data)
```

However when we then inspect the fitted conditional probabilities by calling `model.cpds[1]`, we find that pgmpy has learned the following:

```
+------+------+------+
| A    | A(0) | A(1) |
+------+------+------+
| B(0) | 0.5  | 0.5  |
+------+------+------+
| B(1) | 0.5  | 0.5  |
+------+------+------+
```

when it *should* have learned

```
+------+------+------+
| A    | A(0) | A(1) |
+------+------+------+
| B(0) | 0.0  | 1.0  |
+------+------+------+
| B(1) | 1.0  | 0.0  |
+------+------+------+
```

Can someone please explain to me what is going on here? This is an extremely basic example, and I feel like I'm going crazy. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of pgmpy available for installation through `pip` has a bug that causes it to compute conditional probabilities incorrectly. Cloning the dev repository from git and installing it manually fixes the issue. Thanks to @lstbl for figuring this out here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292738/inconsistencies-between-conditional-probability-calculations-by-hand-and-with-pg